# Proving that the integral $\int_1^2 \frac{\arctan(x)}{x} \,dx$ is less than $1$

Tags: calculus

I am looking to prove that:
$$\int_1^2 \frac{\arctan(x)}{x} \,dx< 1$$

Using Darboux higher sum i can do that pretty easily, however, in order to use Darboux sum (which is given by plugging the value $1$ to the function) I also need to show that the function is descreasing, and things got a little messed up there..

any help?

Comment: ok Forget it, it was a typo of mine!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, the value is less than $1$.

Comment: yes this is true, it is to cold for me in Leipzig!

Comment: Be careful with your mathematical phrasing: don't mix English ("the integral") and symbolic ("<") expressions to obtain things like "The integral $\int_0^2 \cdots dx <1$".

Comment: Thanks @CarlMummert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\int_1^2 \frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\,dx\le \int_1^2 \arctan(x)\,dx$$

or

$$\int_1^2 \frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\,dx\le \arctan(2) \int_1^2 \frac1x\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{2}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}x}{x}dx\leq\int_{1}^{2}\dfrac{\tan^{-1}2}{x}dx=(\tan^{-1}2)(\log 2)<1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $x\in [1,2],$  we have $$ 0.79 \le \tan^{-1}(1)<tan^{-1}(x)< tan^{-1}(2) \le  1.11$$

Thus $$\int_1^2 \frac{arctan(x)}{x} \,dx< 1.11 \int_1^2 \frac{1}{x} \,dx=1.11 ln(2)\le 0.77 <1.$$

Comment: How is this different from my second HINT??

Comment: It is not different at all. They both say the same thing and solve the same problem.

Comment: I posted mine 8 minutes before yours.  It's bad form to post an answer that is redundant.

Comment: I do not look at  other solutions and you can solve problems faster than others. What do you suggest now?  I can delete my answer or I can upvote your hint, please advise.

Comment: I'll let you decide what you think is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It is shown geometrically in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151), for $-\frac\pi2\lt x\lt\frac\pi2$,
$$
\frac{\tan(x)}x\gt1
$$
This means that
$$
\frac{\arctan(x)}x\lt1
$$

Comment: Best answer!  (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach: $f(x)=\frac{\arctan x}{x}$ is a convex function on $[1,2]$, hence by the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality)
$$ \int_{1}^{2}\frac{\arctan x}{x}\,dx \leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\arctan 1}{1}+\frac{\arctan 2}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\arctan(2+\sqrt{5})<\frac{\pi}{4}. $$
Second alternative approach: by the Shafer Fink inequality $\frac{\arctan x}{x}\leq \frac{\pi}{1+2\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, hence the integral is bounded by
$$ \int_{1}^{2}\frac{\pi}{1+2\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx \leq \frac{7}{10}.$$